# Can't generate react test coverage using react-testing-library in windows 10

Tags: reactjs, powershell, react-testing-library, test-coverage

I was trying to generate test coverage for my react tests using `react-testing-library` in windows Powershell. But on running `yarn test .\src\components\ --coverage` PowerShell shows this statement `Invalid testPattern .\src\components\ supplied. Running all tests instead.`.

Running without a path like this `yarn test --coverage` is also not working, it is giving this output

```
Press `a` to run all tests, or run Jest with `--watchAll`.
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|

Watch Usage
 › Press a to run all tests.
 › Press f to run only failed tests.
 › Press q to quit watch mode.
 › Press p to filter by a filename regex pattern.
 › Press t to filter by a test name regex pattern.
 › Press Enter to trigger a test run.
```

How do I run react test in windows PowerShell?

Answer (score 2):

Try using --watchAll=false flag, something like: `yarn test --coverage --watchAll=false`

Answer (score 1):

This command works for me:

> npm t -- --coverage --watchAll=false